# Title is missing on a WPF's tool window when DPI setting 125-150%

Tags: wpf

When WindowStyle="ToolWindow" and ResizeMode="NoResize" and system DPI is 125-150% the text on the titlebar disappears. I'm running Windows 7 and WPF 3.5
Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: yea seems like a wpf bug

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this yesterday.  The ToolWindow part and the DPI are fine, but adding the NoResize causes this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well with the following:

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Title=Blah">
```

Switching to `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"` fixed the issue of the Title text not appearing. So if you aren't set on using a `ToolWindow`, this works too.