# Why doesn't the form title text appear in a FixedToolWindow when windows is set to 120 dpi

Tags: winforms, dpi

In the display screen on windows 7, I set the computer to 125% text size (120dpi). But all of my FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow style forms have no title text in their title bar (this.Text property of the form) when they normally do at 96dpi.

I'm using AutoScaleMode.Font.

If I set the form style to FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle the text thats supposed to be there comes back.

Anyone know a workaround? I'm attached to the window style of FixedToolWindow and I want to keep them looking like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug that was fixed in .Net Framework 4.5.

This bug [also can be reproduced in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922891/title-is-missing-on-a-wpfs-tool-window-when-dpi-setting-125-150) using

```
<Window ... ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ... >
```

Another interesting thing is that you may not notice this bug, if you run your program through Visual Studio (F5 hotkey). Run your executable directly.

Answer (score 0):

FormBorderStyle.SizeableToolWindow looks practically the same and has the text. Except now I have to find out how to disable the resizing.